# missing info for endpoints describe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud

When using the project owner, calling `gcloud endpoints services describe` returns the following:

```
generation: '10'
producerProjectId: wildfire-app-backend
serviceConfig:
  documentation: {}
  id: 2019-11-04r0
  legacy:
    apiV1Name: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
    devconsole:
      consoleApi: NEW
  migration: {}
  name: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
  title: Bifold gRPC API
  usage: {}
```

but when I use a service account that should have most permissions but fails to fetch the service config in a esp container in a private GKE cluster, I get:

```
producerProjectId: wildfire-app-backend
serviceName: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
```

I am wondering what is causing the discrepancy in the 2 results.

EDIT: My service account permissions are:

```
Cloud SQL Client
Editor
Role Viewer
Logs Writer
Monitoring Metric Writer
Owner
Service Management Administrator
Service Config Editor
Service Controller
Storage Admin
Storage Object Viewer
```

and my personal are:

```
App Engine Admin
App Engine Code Viewer
App Engine Deployer
App Engine Service Admin
Project Billing Manager
Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Build Editor
Cloud Build Viewer
Compute OS Admin Login
Service Account User
Owner
Organization Administrator
Project Mover
Storage Admin
```

Comment: Can you describe the roles of your services account? Can you also describe how do you call the gcloud command with your service account?

Comment: Seems like a bug. One thing you may do is add `--log-http` to both commands to get more details on the calls' requests|responses to see whether that provides an explanation. Otherwise, you may wish to file this as a bug on Google's Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere my roles are: Cloud SQL Client
Editor
Role Viewer
Logs Writer
Monitoring Metric Writer
Owner
Service Management Administrator
Service Config Editor
Service Controller
Storage Admin
Storage Object Viewe

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun can you please edit your question with the list of roles for the service account?  With them smooshed all together on one line it can be hard to distinguish names (e.g. it isn't entire clear if you mean 'Cloud SQL Client' and 'Cloud SQL Editor' or 'Cloud SQL Client' and 'Editor').  Plus, editing them into the question makes it easier for future readers to find them.

Comment: @robsiemb fair point. Done

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access details concerning containers, you may want to consider adding one of these [roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam).

Edit: I have created a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/144301222) for this specific scenario.

Comment: While link itself can contain an answer, as it can be changed/removed it's better to add some quotes here.